# How would I implement code in a .h file into the main.cpp file?

Tags: c++

I have a c++ project I am working on. I am a little stumped at the moment. I need a little help. I need to implement code from the .h file into the main.cpp file and I am not sure how to do that.

For example code code from main.cpp:

```
switch (choice){
case 1: // open an account
    {
    cout << "Please enter the opening balence: $ ";
    cin >> openBal;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the account number: ";
    cin >> accountNum;
    cout << endl;

    break;
    }
case 2:// check an account
    {
    cout << "Please enter the account number: ";
    cin >> accountNum;
    cout << endl;
    break;
    }
```

and code from the .h file:

```
void display(ostream& out) const;
// displays every item in this list through out

bool retrieve(elemType& item) const;
// retrieves item from this list
// returns true if item is present in this list and
//              element in this list is copied to item
//         false otherwise

// transformers
void insert(const elemType& item);
// inserts item into this list
// preconditions: list is not full and
//                item not present in this list
// postcondition: item is in this list
```

In the .h file you would need to use the void insert under transformer in the main.cpp under case 1. How would you do that? Any help is apprecaited. I hope I didn't confuse anyone on what I am needing to know how to do. Thanks

Comment: include the .h file in your main.cpp file and do the implementation. If your .cpp is not the startup file ( not having main), then you would have to write another .cpp file and then link to the main program.

Comment: I do have the .h file include at the top of the main.cpp file

Answer (score 1):

In `main.cpp` you need to include your header file at the top, like this:

```
#include "header_file.h"
```

Now you should be able to freely call `insert()` under `case 1:` like you wanted.

However, these function declarations aren't really going to do much without implementations. So, you have a couple of choices. You can put the implementations in `main.cpp`, or you could make a new `.cpp` file where the implementations of these functions are held. (Don't worry, the linker will take care of the whole "separate source file" business)

The very basic method for declaring functions in a header file and implementing them in a cpp file can be outlined as followed:

foo.h file:

```
void insert(const elemType& item); // This is your declaration
```

foo.cpp file:

```
#include "foo.h"
void insert(const elemType& item)
{
    // Function should do its job here, this is your implementation
}
```

Comment: I have another .cpp file that contains all of the implementaions for the functions in the .h file. So I am not sure if I need to include anything from the other .cpp file in the main for the functions to go through.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What happens is, after the source files are all compiled, the linker (as is implied by its name), links them together as if they are one big compiled source file. You don't need to worry if the implementations are in separate source files, the linker should take care of this.

Comment: okay. But I still don't know how to use the insert in the main.cpp under case one when the implementation is under another .cpp file

Comment: No, I don't get any errors. The program will run but it doesn't do what it should do becasue the implementations are under another .cpp file and I don't know how to use the .h insert

Comment: Firstly, at the top of main.cpp type `#include header.h` where header.h is the name of the header file with the declarations in it. Now, under `case 1:` you can type, say, `insert( item );`, where item is an `elemType` object. It seems your question has no mention of the `elemType` class/struct, so I can't really help more here.

Comment: I can guarantee you, your problems are not likely due to the implementation being in another cpp file. Something else is wrong here.

Comment: okay here is the code under another .cpp file that goes with the .h file that contains insert.void ListDA::insert(const elemType& item)
// inserts item into this list
// preconditions: list is not full and
//                item not present in this list
// postcondition: item is in this list
{
 list[size++] = item;

Comment: is that helpful for you to provide me how to use the insert in the main.cpp file

Comment: I'm sorry, it's hard to say. I'm not really sure if you're asking about the function itself and how to use it, or whether you're having troubles using it *syntactically*. Is the insert function something you wrote, or someone else? If someone else wrote it, you had better contact them as to how it should be used in your program.

Comment: I need to know how to use the insert function syntactically in the case 1

Answer (score 0):

Well, you if you have included the header file, you should be able to implement any function that you have declared in that header. For example, you wanted to implement the `insert` function, your main.cpp should look like this:

```
#include "myhfile.h"

void insert(const elemType& item)
{
    // implement here
}

int main()
{
    // your switch here
    // you can now use insert(item) because it is implemented above
}
```